# Center-padding output that contain '\n'

Tags: python

### **Hello There!**

---

Suppose I have a string:

```
a = 'Hello.\nWelcome.\nHave a nice day.'
```

And I print it like this:

```
> print (
f"{'-' * 16}\n"
f"{a}\n"
f"{'-' * 16}\n"
)

# OUTPUT
----------------
Hello.
Welcome.
Have a nice day.
----------------
```

---

Now, I want to keep the alignment of the string but the pad the whole output to right.
Something like this:

```
          ----------------
          Hello.
          Welcome.
          Have a nice day.
          ----------------
```

**These don't work as intended:**

print (a.center(50))

print (f"{a : ^50}")

---

***I want to achieve this without importing any functions or libraries.***

I am a beginner in python, any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `center` on the *formatted* string:

```
print(("-"*16).center(50))
for line in a.split('\n'):
    print((f"{line:16}").center(50))
print(("-"*16).center(50))
```

Comment: Thank you SM. This works perfectly!! 

Can you please explain what `{line:16}` does?

Comment: It formats `line` in a 16-char left-justified field.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry to bother again, but can you link a source where I can learn about this `line:16` thing (I couldn't find it)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you learn about `print (f"{a : ^50}")`?

Comment: [Here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-alignment-in-python-f-string/)

Comment: Then what more do you need to know about "this `line:16` thing"?

Comment: Alignment is `{line : >n}`, `{line : <n}` or`{line : ^n}`. I don’t understand what `{line : n}` means.

Comment: If alignment and just size isn't specified, default alignment for that type of data is used.  For a string, it is left-alignment.